# Time dependent Has and Belongs-to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on a rails app where the associations between data change with time. I've created a model for the associations:

```
   create_table :accounts_numbers do |t|
     t.integer :number_id
     t.integer :account_id
     t.date :start_date
     t.date :end_date
```

And, so far, I have a simple model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :numbers, :through => accounts_numbers
end
```

But instead of

```
@account.numbers
```

I need something like

```
@account.numbers_at(Date.new(2010,2,3))
```

I thought I could use `:conditions`, but I wouldn't haven't seen a way to tell `has_and_belongs_to_many` to create a parameterized field. I've also looked into `named_scope`, but that only seems to return accounts, not numbers.

More importantly, this pattern is going to cover many relationships in my code, so would there be a way to coin a `time_dependent_has_and_belongs_to_many` for use all over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much more searching, I finally found out what to do; In the `/lib` dir of my project, I created a module, `TimeDependent`:

```
module TimeDependent
    def at(date)
        find(:all, :conditions=>["start_date <= ? AND ? < end_date"], date, date)
    end
end
```

So, my model becomes

```
require "TimeDependent"
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accounts_numbers
    has_many :numbers, :through => :accounts_numbers, :extend => TimeDependent
end
```

Which allows me to do exactly what I want:

```
@numbers = @account.numbers.at(Date.new(2010,2,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't this be done by writing a function for Object?

```
class Object
  def numbers_at(time)
    start = time.to_date
    end = time.advance(:days => 1).to_date

    AccountNumber.join(:accounts, :numbers).where("time BETWEEN(?, ?)", start, end)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's the "Does something here" I'm not quite sure about. I want to leverage ActiveRecord as much as I can.

Comment: Okay, now it does it x_x. Although I'm assuming you're passing in a Time and not a Date. If you want that changed, just ask.

Comment: start and end should be fields in `accounts_numbers`. Does this even perform any joins?